# I need the my jquery counter to reset after the last img within a div

Tags: jquery

I need to add a page counter to the the bottom of each `<div>` with a class of **page_container**.

I need it to reset the page counter to 1 for each div tag with a class of **resource_container**.

Right now my code just keeps counting the total **page_container** and does not reset to 1 when a new **resource_container** starts.

Here is my jquery:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
        buildPageBottoms('img');
    });

    function  buildPageBottoms(strWhichTag) {
        var cPageCount = 1;

        $(strWhichTag).each(function() {
           $(this).after($("<div class='pagenumber'><p>page " + cPageCount++ + "</p></div>"));
        });
    }
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="resource_container">
  <div class="page_container" id="1"><img src="01a.png"> 
  </div>
  <div class="page_container" id="2"><img src="02a.png">  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="resource_container">
  <div class="page_container" id="1"><img src="01b.png"> 
  </div>
  <div class="page_container" id="2"><img src="02b.png"> 
  </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: edited!! added `<` here `img src="01a.png">`.. since i think that is a typo..

Comment: Could you show, for the posted example, what you want the HTML/DOM to become *after* it's been manipulated with jQuery?

Comment: **ID should always be unique.. and better be a string than a number**

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    buildPageBottoms('img', 'resource_container');
});

function buildPageBottoms(strWhichTag, strSplitterTag) {
    $('.' + strSplitterTag).each(function () {
        var cPageCount = 1;
        $('.' + strSplitterTag + ' > ' + strWhichTag).each(function () {
            $(this).after($("<div class='pagenumber'><p>page " + cPageCount+++"</p></div>"));
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
$("document").ready(function () {  
   $(".resource_container").each(function() { // Loop through resource_containers
        var pageCount = 0;
        $(this).find(".page_container").each(function(){ // Loop through child page_containers
            $(this).append("<div class='pagenumber'><p>page " + (pageCount++) + "</p></div>");
        });
    });
});
```

Also fix your HTML to:

```
<div class="resource_container">
    <div class="page_container" id="1"><img src="01a.png" /> 
  </div>
    <div class="page_container" id="2"><img src="02a.png" />  
  </div>
</div>

<div class="resource_container">
    <div class="page_container" id="1"><img src="01b.png" /> 
  </div>
    <div class="page_container" id="2"><img src="02b.png" /> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

You forgot to close your `img` tags and had an `</div>` tag. As bipen said you should supply unique ID's to your elements, and start with a letter unless you are using HTML5.

http://jsfiddle.net/6YZK8/